# send logs to external elasticsearch from openshift projects

Tags: elasticsearch, openshift, fluentd

I'm trying to send specific openshift project logs to unsecured external elastic search.

I have tried solution which is there in https://github.com/richm/docs/releases/tag/20190205142308.  But found that it will work only when ELS is secured.

Later I have tried using elasticsearch plugin also by adding in output-applications.conf.

output-applications.conf:

```
   <match *.*>
   @type elasticsearch
   host xxxxx
   port 9200
   logstash_format true

   </match>
```

All other files are same which is described in https://github.com/richm/docs/releases/tag/20190205142308 #Application logs from specific namespaces/pods/containers

Included output-applications.conf in fluent.conf file.
In fluentd logs except "[info]: reading config file path="/etc/fluent/fluent.conf" " this message i dont see any other things and data is not reaching to elasticsearch

Can anyone tell how to proceed?

Comment: can you check the log and paste the log here?